# How to make Flask Requests module authenticate?

Tags: api, flask, python-requests

I built my own API with flask, but now I'm trying to write a script to consume the API and the Requests module won't make it past the log in.

**The Form**
The form has jut a 'username' input, 'password', and I'm also using flask-wtf to implement csrf protection, so there is a 'csrf_token' hidden input.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=20)])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=25)])
```

**The Route**

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    form = LoginForm()

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)

    elif request.method == 'POST':

        if form.validate_on_submit():

            credentials = {'username': request.form['username'],
                            'password': request.form['password']}

            try:
                r = requests.post('http://api.domain.com:80/authenticate', data=credentials)
                response = r.json()
            except Exception as e:
                print('JSON Auth Error: {}'.format(e))
            else:
                if r.status_code is 200:

                    session['access_token'] = response['access_token']
                    session['refresh_token'] = response['refresh_token']

                    return redirect('/')

        return render_template('login.html', form=form, error='invalid')
```

**The API Endpoint**

```
@api.route('/authenticate', methods=['POST'])
def authenticate():

    # form data
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']

    # check if user exists
    try: 
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(e)

    if user and password == user.password:

        tokens = generate_tokens()

        return jsonify({'access_token': tokens['access'], 'refresh_token': tokens['refresh']}), 200

    else:

        return jsonify({'message': 'invalid login'}), 401
```

**The API Resource Endpoint I am trying to access**

```
@api.route('/pending', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def pending():
```

**The @login_required verification method**

```
def tokens_valid():

    if 'access_token' and 'refresh_token' in session:

        # retrieve access and refresh tokens from session cookie
        tokens = {'access_token': session['access_token'],
                    'refresh_token': session['refresh_token']}

        # validate token endpoint
        try:
            r = requests.post('http://api.domain.com/validate', data=tokens)
            response = r.json()

        except Exception as e:
            print('JSON Token Error: {}'.format(e))

        else:

            if r.status_code is 200:

                if response['message'] == 'valid access token':
                    return True

                elif response['message'] == 'new access token':

                    #set new tokens
                    session['access_token'] = response['access_token']
                    session['refresh_token'] = response['refresh_token']

                    return True

    return False
```

**What I have tried**

> v.1

```
def login():

    credentials = {'username': 'username',
                    'password': 'password'}

    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.post('http://sub.domain.com/auth/login', data=credentials)

    return s
```

> v.2

```
def login():
    login_form = requests.get('http://sub.domain.com/auth/login')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(login_form.text, "html.parser")
    csrf = soup.find('input', id='csrf_token').get('value')

    credentials = {'username': 'username',
                    'password': 'password',
                    'csrf_token': csrf}

    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.post('http://sub.domain.com/auth/login', data=credentials)

    return s
```

> v.3

```
from flask import Flask, session
def login():

    credentials = {'username': 'username',
                    'password': 'password'}

    r = requests.post('http://api.domain.com/authenticate', data=credentials)
    tokens = r.json()

    session['access_token'] = tokens['access_token']
    session['refresh_token'] = tokens['refresh_token']
```

So far I can get the '/authenticate' api endpoint to return my session tokens, but i can't access the protected resource because i can't seem to save them to my session any how.

Can anyone help me figure this out?